# "failure to parse lease: could not get netmask from lease" when connecting to an AP generated by hostapd

Tags: 22.04, dhcp, wireless-access-point

I have a Linux device running that generates an access point using hostapd and udhcpd (I followed [this](https://www.engicam.com/art/164871/WIFIBLUETOOTH-STERLING-LWB) guide). I used to connect to it with my Ubuntu 16 PC, but after the update to Ubuntu 22 I can't connect anymore. The system log on the client shows the following error:

> [1702642014.5815] dhcp4 (wlx000f005d7551): failure to parse
> lease: could not get netmask from lease

The lease stored in /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.leases is the following:

```
lease {
  interface "wlx000f005d7551";
  fixed-address 192.168.3.10;
  option dhcp-lease-time 864000;
  option dhcp-message-type 5;
  option dhcp-server-identifier 192.168.3.1;
  renew 5 2023/12/15 10:34:47;
  rebind 5 2023/12/15 10:34:47;
  expire 5 2023/12/15 10:34:47;
}
```

The output of `ip addr` on the server is the following:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:25:ca:6b:d3:e5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:25:ca:6b:d3:e5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.3.1/24 brd 192.168.3.255 scope global wlan1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::225:caff:fe6b:d3e5/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

According to the server (using `dumpleases`), the lease has been sent and the IP has been correctly assigned. I tried with my Ubuntu 22 laptop with identical dhclient configuration, and it works well. The only difference is that on my PC I have an USB wireless adapter and UFW enabled. How can I fix this?

EDIT: manually setting IP and mask for this interface works.